# Why is VS Code unable to import the timeit module in my program?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, python-module, timeit

This is the code I'm trying to execute...I have imported and used the timeit module to check which function executes faster, `fibonacci_recur` or `fibonacci_iter`. I'm executing this python file in VS Code(version: 1.41.1(user setup))

```
    #Importing timeit
    import timeit
    def fibonacci_recur(num): 
        if num<0: 
            print("Incorrect input") 
        elif num==0: 
            return 0 
        elif num==1: 
            return 1
        else: 
            return fibonacci_recur(num-1)+fibonacci_recur(num-2) 

    def fibonacci_iter(num):
          if (num == 0):
                  return 0
          elif (num == 1):
                  return 1
          elif (num >1 ):
                  fn = 0
                  fn1 = 1
                  fn2 = 2
                  for i in range(3, num):
                          fn = fn1+fn2
                          fn1 = fn2
                          fn2 = fn
                  return fn
          else:
                  return -1

    print("{:9}{:9}{:9}".format("Number","Iterative","Recursive"))
    for i in range(10,35,5):
            #Using the timeit module
            ("{:9}{:9}{:9}".format(i,timeit.timeit(fibonacci_iter, number=100000),timeit.timeit(fibonacci_recur, number=100000)))
```

This is the error I get while debugging:

Could not load source `'<timeit-src>'`: Source unavailable.

launch.json

```
    {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

What could be the problem and how should I fix this?

Comment: make sure you have timeit installed in the python version and environment that you use to execute this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required package was `time` not `timeit`

```
import time
```

To find time elapsed for a function:

```
start = time.time()
recursive_fibonacci(n)
end = time.time()
print(end - start, 'seconds')
```